# When I click on the log out section of WooCommerce, it goes to the 404 page and does not log out of the account

Tags: woocommerce

The output link address is the following value:

```
https://example.com/my-account/logout/
```

[image: my account]

The exit link works in the part of the dashboard that I have specified in the image and the value is as follows:

```
https://example.com/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=09d89da7bd
```

What is this value **(?_wpnonce=09d89da7bd)**?

Comment: May be try to reset your permalinks by saving them once more… Nonce is a WordPress security feature: see [this documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/)